# How Can I display values of variables in a "PHP contextual filter code" to debug my code?

Tags: 7, views, debugging

I have to use PHP code in contextual filter code in a "Arguments/Contextual Filters" of a view:

```
global $user;
$uid=$user->uid;

$pid=db_query("select pid from profile where uid='$uid';")->fetchField();

$equipo=db_query("select field_equipo_proyecto_target_id from field_data_field_equipo_proyecto where entity_id='$uid';")->fetchField();

$num_equipo=db_query("select field_num_equipo_proyecto_value from field_data_field_num_equipo_proyecto where entity_id='$equipo';")->fetchField();;

printf("%02d",intval($num_equipo));
return sprintf("%02d",intval($num_equipo));
```

I think I have some error because I can´t get a correct value. I would like to know how display variables such as `$num_equipo`, etc to debug my code easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on what Adrian offered, I would add the [Devel Debug Log](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_debug_log) module.  I had a similar problem trying to debug code that ran from a rule, and, I found it easy to write the contents of variables to the log.  I then went to **Reports > Debug Messages** and see what I needed to debug my code.  The Debug Log module provides a *ddl($message)* function that is easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

Install the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module with the [Search Krumo](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_krumo) module and you will be able to use the `dpm()` function.

> Devel
>
> - Helper functions for Drupal developers and inquisitive admins.
> - Enable the included Kint submodule as for pretty print of variables. kint($array) function is provided, which pretty prints arrays. Useful
>     during development. Similarly, a ddebug_backtrace() is offerred.

You can read how to use the Devel module at: [Debugging Drupal](http://ratatosk.net/drupal/tutorials/debugging-drupal.html) (a page which gives a brief overview of some of the tools you can use to make Drupal development and debugging easier).